# GridView onItemClickListener and onItemSelected not reaching callback functions

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

Initially I was the adapter's getView() to create views programmatically where just an image loaded, `onItemClick` on the gridview was working here. I needed more complex views in each cell so I changed the getView() to use XML files and now none of the gridview listeners work. Switching back to the programmatic views getView() works as expected.

So here is my XML for the adapter cells:

**Note**: I was using the same kinds of extended objects (RecyclingImageView, ImageViewTintState) for the programmatic views so seeing the code for them shouldn't be necessary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/containerView"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.whosay.talent.views.RecyclingImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:tint="@color/image_click_state"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<com.whosay.talent.views.ImageViewTintState
    android:id="@+id/videoIconView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_play_img"
    app:tint="@color/image_click_state"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

as you can see, I have tried the `onFocusable` trick that other questions have suggested. I have also tried using more rudimentary views such as `ImageView`, but it seems like anything with more than one view in a gridview cell will disrupt the item clicking method. Also, adding onClickListener's to individual views within the `getView` does not work either, even after adding `clickable:true`

And here is my Gridview's xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by adding onClickListeners onto elements within the `getView()` , still baffled about why I had to resort to this

Comment: whenever there are clickable views in an item, the default OnItemSelected won't fire. You have to individually assign clicklisteners to the clickable sub-items or to the viewgroup "row".

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in these statements:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

I don't think you need *any* of these, especially `android:clickable="true"`. This statement essentially blocks the click event from propagating to the `GridView`, which normally would call `onItemClick(...)`. Since your `FrameLayout` is clickable (and hence, consumes the event), the grid item isn't.

Try removing all of these statements from every tag in your xml. You will also need to remove the `OnClickListeners` that you set in `getView(...)` since they set the flag `clickable` to true.

There's nothing wrong with setting `OnClickListeners` on widgets inside each grid item. But then, you cannot use the `listSelector` which provided visual feedback on item click. And if you require long-press functionality, you need to set `OnLongClickListeners`.

In my opinion, this is extra work that need not be done.

Comment: I originally didn't have any clickable or focusable tags in the XML, I added them to try to make it work as expected. There are other similar questions regarding gridviews where the solution was to add those focusable tags or some other combination. If I didn't make a reference to that, the question probably would have been marked duplicate and closed and not have helped anyone. Stackoverflow problem :)

Comment: @CQM :) I know. Okay, the problem you describe is that the `GridView` isn't seeing the click event. Which means, the click event is being consumed on its way from your xml up to the `GridView`. So, either `RecyclingImageView` or the `ImageViewTintState` or the `FrameLayout` itself is consuming the click. Do any of these views have an OnTouchListener or an OnCLickListener attached?

Comment: `ImageViewTintState` does react to clicks, but what was baffling about this is that I was originally generating this view programmatically, using the same view objects. The `ImageViewTintState` would show it's click state when touched and the gridview would still go to `onItemSelected` so I could handle clicks the way it was intended

Comment: @CQM `ImageViewTintState` may very well be the culprit. But it seems that you have a working solution already. If your requirement changes, and you need to get `onItemClick(...)` working, post your adapter, and custom view code.